# Remove unicode <+f0b7> from Corpus text

Tags: r, tm

I'm having a pretty stubborn issue... I can't seem to remove the `<+f0b7>` and `<+f0a0>` string from Corpora that have loaded from `*.txt` files into R:

**UPDATE** Here's a link to the sample `.txt` file: **https://db.tt/qTRKpJYK**

`Corpus(DirSource("./SomeDirectory/txt/"), readerControl = list(reader = readPlain))`

```
title
 professional staff - contract - permanent position
software c microfocus cobol unix btrieve ibm vm-cms vsam cics jcl
accomplishments
 <+f0b7>
<+f0a0>
responsible maintaining billing system interfaced cellular switching system <+f0b7>
<+f0a0>
developed unix interface ibm mainframe ericsson motorola att cellular switches
```

I've tried adding it to:

```
badWords <- unique(c(stopwords("en"), 
          stopwords("SMART")[stopwords("SMART") != "c"],
          as.character(1970:2050),
          "<U+F0B7>", "<+f0b7>",
          "<U+F0A0>", "<+f0a0>",
          "january",  "jan",
          "february",   "feb",
          "march",  "mar",
          "april",  "apr",
          "may",    "may",
          "june",   "jun",
          "july",   "jul",
          "august", "aug",
          "september",  "sep",
          "october",    "oct",
          "november",   "nov",
          "december",   "dec"))
```

And using:

```
tm_map(candidates.Corpus, removeWords, badWords)
```

But that doesn't work somehow. I've also tried to regexp it out with something like `gsub("<+f0a0>", "", tmp, perl = FALSE)`, and that works on a string within R, but somehow these characters are still showing up when I read a `.txt` file.

Is there something unique about these characters? How do I get rid of them?

Comment: So are you saying the string `"<U+F0B7>"` is appearing in your text, or are you saying the unicode character `<U+F0B7>` is appearing in your text? Does R print this value to the screen?

Comment: When I `inspect()` the Corpus element, R actually prints this value to my screen.

Comment: Please provide data to reproduce this error.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, here's a link to a sample .txt file: https://db.tt/qTRKpJYK

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The problem is that your data has an unusual unicode character in it. In R, we typically escape this character as "\uf0b7". But when `inspect()` prints it's data, it encodes it as "". Observe

```
sample<-c("Crazy \uf0b7 Character")
cp<-Corpus(VectorSource(sample))
inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(cp))

# A document-term matrix (1 documents, 3 terms)
# 
# Non-/sparse entries: 3/0
# Sparsity           : 0%
# Maximal term length: 9 
# Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
# 
#     Terms
# Docs <U+F0B7> character crazy
#    1        1         1     1
```

(actually i had to create this output on a Windows machine running R 3.0.2 - it worked fine on my Mac running R 3.1.0).

Unfortunately you will not be able to remove this with remove words because the regular expression used in that function required that word boundaries appear on both sides of the "word" and since this doesn't seem to be a recognized character for a boundary. See

```
gsub("\uf0b7","",sample)
# [1] "Crazy  Character"
gsub("\\b\uf0b7\\b","",sample)
#[1] "Crazy  Character"
```

So we can write our own function we can use with `tm_map`. Consider

```
removeCharacters <-function (x, characters)  {
gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)(%s)", paste(characters, collapse = "|")), "", x, perl = TRUE)
}
```

which is basically the removeWords function just without the boundary conditions. Then we can run

```
cp2 <- tm_map(cp, removeCharacters, c("\uf0b7","\uf0a0"))
inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(cp2))

# A document-term matrix (1 documents, 2 terms)
# 
# Non-/sparse entries: 2/0
# Sparsity           : 0%
# Maximal term length: 9 
# Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
# 
#     Terms
# Docs character crazy
#    1         1     1
```

and we see those unicode characters are no longer there.

Comment: Man, you've saved me. I had issue with U+2007. It's funny thing why the `U+2007` known as 'figure space' (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm) is not working with something like `gsub("\\s+", "", x)`? Maybe space != space. Any other gsub tricks didn't work, but your function done it. Thanks!