# In RTF, what is the meaning of \u-3913?

Tags: unicode, outlook, rtf

I'm parsing RTF data in .MSG file created by Outlook. One thing I stumbled upon is:

```
mso-level-text:\u-3913 ?
mso-level-text:\u-3929 ?
```

"\u-3913 ?" denotes a middot character. However, I couldn't identify its Unicode code. Also, I didn't find the meaning of "\u-XXXX ?" strings at all. Neither decimal 3913 nor hex 3913 denote a middot. I also checked UTF-8 value for middot. Not even close. Googling explains the meaning of "\uXXXX ?" only, not "\u-XXXX ?".

The same for 3929 code.

How to get the right characters from the above?

Comment: `\u` uses 16 bit signed values where values > 32767 are expressed as negatives, so the value is -3913. I thought you could simply deduct (32767 * 2) but that does not give a middot ...

Comment: Well, -3913 is F0B7 (which is invalid character) but just B7 is middot! For -3929 it's A7 (paragraph). I think I can make it from this point. Thanks!

Comment: RTF demands that Unicode codepoints larger than 32767 are represented as negative values.  Makes it 65536 - 3913 == U+F0B7.  It is in the private use area, [here is another victim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147816/remove-unicode-f0b7-from-corpus-text).  Really rather best to not parse RTF yourself, leave it up to RichTextBox.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. Actually, I don't have RichTextBox. I'm writing a library which converts MSG files into MIME format, and I need to get HTML from that RTF. The only part which is still a mystery for me is why Outlook uses (and renders) middot as F0B7 (while it should be just B7).

Comment: What value of `\ucN` appears before the `\u-3913`? That will tell you how many bytes the `-3913` value occupies when converted to a Unicode character. This is covered in the RTF spec. For instance, `\uc1` would be one byte, thus `-3913` would be `0xB7` (U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT) and not `0xF0B7` (U+F0B7 PRIVATE USE CHARACTER).

Comment: It's "mso-level-text:\u-3913 ?", no \ucN prefix there.

Comment: "A default of 1 should be assumed if no \uc keyword has been seen in the current or outer scopes." - https://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading9

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this problem as well. As mentioned in a comment by Hans Passant you need first to add 65536 (0x10000) which yields 0xF0B7. The next thing is that Word occasionally writes SYMBOL_CHARSET (nonUnicode) characters in the range U+F020..U+F0FF instead of U+0020..U+00FF. The charset is specified by the \fcharset2 control word in the RTF document. Likely this is "\fcharset2 Symbol;". B7 in the Symbol font character encoding is a bullet point, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(typeface)

With this reasoning 3929 would yield -3929 + 65536 = 0xF0A7 and 0xA7 in the Symbol font corresponds to clubs (the playing card suit).

Answer (score 0):

Some RTF writer applications use the private area character \uf0b7 to represent a middot / bullet character. The parameter value is 61623.

To fix this, you may replace this character with \u2022 which represents a middot / bullet.

Example code:

```
char convertToUnicodeChar(int paramValue) {
    char unicodeChar;
    if (paramValue < 0) {
        unicodeChar = (char) (paramValue + 65_536);
    } else {
        if (paramValue == 61_623) {
            // Private Use Area character used by some writers - '\uf0b7'
            //noinspection UnnecessaryUnicodeEscape
            unicodeChar = '\u2022'; // middot / bullet
        } else {
            unicodeChar = (char) paramValue;
        }
    }
    return unicodeChar;
}
```