# Can't remove special characters from data frame in R

Tags: r, unicode

I have a snippet of data frame:

```
1                       137                      411    NA
2             45.7  (13.38)            45.4  (13.15)    NA
3                                                       NA
4   37<U+2007><U+2007>27.0% 135<U+2007><U+2007>32.8%    NA
5  100<U+2007><U+2007>73.0% 276<U+2007><U+2007>67.2%    NA
```

There are some unicode spaces which I'd like to remove with:

`adf <- apply(adf, 2, function(x) gsub("<U\\+2007>", "", x))`

But this works only apparently. Printing in console there are two white spaces instead of U2007 and after conversion:

`adf <- as.data.frame(adf[,colSums(is.na(adf)) < nrow(adf)], stringsAsFactors = F, check.names = F)`

these unicode characters are again in the text like in the beginning.

How to change them to real spaces or get rid off?

I've checked some patterns from similar threads but this also doesn't work:

`adf <- apply(adf, 2, function(x) gsub("[<].*[>]", " ", x))`

**EDIT**

I've found the solution thanks of this thread: [Remove unicode <+f0b7> from Corpus text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147816/remove-unicode-f0b7-from-corpus-text)

`gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)(%s)", paste("\U2007", collapse = "|")), " ", x, perl = TRUE)`

This probably can be applied for more Unicode characters. My data was loaded from the website with `UTF-8` encoding. I hope this above statement will work for more 'bushes' which grow between words of `html` space.

Comment: Can you provide the source code for creating the `adf` data frame?

Comment: Perhaps the column is a factor - try converting it to `as.character` before using your code

Comment: @Peter.k I guess the link refers to your own question.

Comment: Sorry for mistake - I've edited the post.

Comment: @Andrew Gustar. All table is of character type so changing again didn't work. I don't know why - encoding issues are always tricky for me.